# Writing a clojurescript REPL in clojurescript

Tags: clojure, embed, read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript

I'm interested in embedding a clojurescript REPL in a webpage.  How could I write a clojurescript evaluator in clojurescript, so that I can compile that to javascript and embed the javascript in the webpage?  I can't go down the route of compiling the clojurescript to javascript in the cloud.

Answer (score 4):

Now it's possible :))
http://app.gadjett.com/cljs_compiler/index-dev.html

Github 
https://github.com/viebel/klipse

Comment: @duncan you should try klipse

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this as ClojureScript does not bootstrap itself. Currently a non-goal for the project, though I'm sure somebody could pursue the idea in a fork.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`clojurescript.net`](http://clojurescript.net/), and the source is available [here](https://github.com/kanaka/cljs-bootstrap).

Or [clojurescript.io](http://clojurescript.io/), which uses [`re-plumb`](https://github.com/ScalaConsultants/replumb).